# Control MagSafe LEDs on Apple Silicon MacBook

Tags: macos

I am wondering how to control the LED on the MagSafe 3 charger from MacOS.

I know that it's possible because the (closed-source) [AlDente](https://apphousekitchen.com/feature-explanation-control-magsafe-led/) controls MagSafe 2 and 3 LEDs to turn green when the laptop reaches the set battery limit (i.e. 80%).

I would like to implement the same thing in the free & open-source alternative [battery](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery) or even disable the LED outright as I find it distracting. However, I have been unable to find any other programs that enable this or reference to how it's done anywhere online.

The only relevant thing I could find was [this](https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter), but it isn't clear to me what part of its code controls the LED.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As per discussion in [this topic](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery/issues/71), the magsafe LED can be manageable via smc tool that is integrated into the [battery open-sourced project](https://github.com/actuallymentor/battery).

```
sudo smc -k ACLC -w <color_code>
```

Where `color_code` is experienced as:

```
| Color Code | Description                     |
|------------|---------------------------------|
| 00         | Restore to system control       |
| 01         | Off                             |
| 03         | Green                           |
| 04         | Orange                          |
| 06         | Slow Blinking Orange            |
| 07         | Fast Blinking Orange            |
| 25         | Blinks Orange, then LED goes Off|
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a poke at the repos you pointed to suggests that https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter repo is just an AppleScript wrapper.  I wrote the following Python code to dump the contents of `charge-limiter/src/Charge Limiter.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt`:

```py
print(open("main.scpt", 'rb').read()[38:5786].decode('utf-16-be'))
```

which showed me it doesn't do much, other than call the included `bclm` binary.

The charge-limiter's README suggests that `bclm` comes from https://github.com/zackelia/bclm (which in turn mostly just wraps code from https://github.com/beltex/SMCKit and doesn't seem to have changed since 2017).  The important code in bclm seems to be in https://github.com/zackelia/bclm/blob/master/Sources/bclm/main.swift which is just calling `getKey` and `writeData` from `SMCKit`.

I also see references to https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/ which seems to contain code that might be useful.  Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

M1 macs and Intel macs have very different SMC protocols, and godly-devotion's charge-limiter specifically supports Intel macs. It appears that instead of SMC, the MagSafe LED is on an I2C bus (Asahi Linux recently added support for MagSafe, and [their device tree](https://github.com/AsahiLinux/linux/blob/a189eadd37058cf4dd958d1861bc0bf09f21eea9/arch/arm64/boot/dts/apple/t8112-j413.dts#L76) defines `&i2c0` as MagSafe).

Finding an I2C API for MacOS is difficult, and the only relevant file I found was on [Apple's open source portal](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOGraphics/IOGraphics-128/IOGraphicsFamily/IOKit/i2c/IOI2CInterface.h.auto.html) in a graphics library, so it may be entirely unrelated. The other devices on Asahi's I2C list are speakers. Maybe someone here knows about I2C on mac!

Also, I watched my SMC keys using the smc utility from [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl) and was unable to find any (readable) SMC key corresponding to the LED state.

Edit: searching the apple opensource GitHub I found [this file](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/PowerManagement/blob/bb4189504cabd0898ab3c136b15a537209465bc9/pmconfigd/BatteryTimeRemaining.m#L3959) which mentions the charging lights.